# mySql sum a column and return only entries with and entry in last 10 minutes

Tags: datetime, mysql, subquery, sum

heres a table, the time when the query runs i.e now is 2010-07-30 22:41:14

```
number | person | timestamp
45       mike     2008-02-15 15:31:14
56       mike     2008-02-15 15:30:56
67       mike     2008-02-17 13:31:14
34       mike     2010-07-30 22:31:14
56       bob      2009-07-30 22:37:14
67       bob      2009-07-30 22:37:14
22       tom      2010-07-30 22:37:14
78       fred     2010-07-30 22:37:14
```

Id like a query that can add up the number for each person. Then only display the name totals which have a recent entry say last 60 minutes. The difficult seems to be, that although its possible to use AND `timestamp` > now( ) - INTERVAL 600, this has the affect of stopping the full sum of the number.

the results I would from above are

```
Mike 202
tom  22
fred 78
```

bob is not included his latest entry is not recent enough its a year old! mike although he has several old entries is valid because he has one entry recently - but key, it still adds up his full 'number' and not just those with the time period.

go on get your head round that one in a single query ! and thanks

andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `HAVING` clause:

```
select name, sum(number), max(timestamp_column)
from table
group by name
HAVING max( timestamp_column) > now( ) - INTERVAL 600;
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a solution with two queries joined together... don't know how I forgot the HAVING clause. Incidentally, I don't believe you need to include the timestamp_column in your select list unless it's needed for display.

Comment: yes, this looks like the correct answer vs my lazy version below :)

Comment: djacobsen: for many RDBMSes, you don't. For the OP's mysql, you don't. For the SQL Standard, you do, so I included it to be portable and safe.

Comment: I like the idea of this - however I'm currently getting the equivalent of tom 302, it seems to have taken one name (a correct one) and returned totals of everything not the single person, I've tried taking the max out - but no luck - Andrew

Comment: It's returning the sum for all rows?

Answer (score 0):

andrew - in the spirit of education, i'm not going to show the query (actually, i'm being lazy but don't tell anyone) :).

basically tho', you'd have to do a subselect within your main criteria select. in psuedo code it would be:

```
select person, total as (select sum(number) from table1 t2 where t2.person=t1.person) 
from table1 t1 where timestamp > now( ) - INTERVAL 600
```

that will blow up, but you get the gist...
jim